# Proving a linear functional on a Banach space is continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ be its proper closed subspace, i.e $Y \lneq X$. For some $x_0 \in X \setminus Y$, I constructed the following functional

$\gamma: Y \oplus \mathbb{R}x_0\to \mathbb{R}$ by defining $\gamma (y+tx_0) = t$.

It is easy to check $\gamma$ is linear, but I don't know how to show $\gamma$ is continuous. I'd appreciate it if you'd help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Projection onto a coordinate is always continuous. Remember, you want to show that given an open set in the codomain, you can find an open set in the domain which maps inside. Since your codomain is $\mathbb{R}$ you may assume you're looking at something like $(t_0-\epsilon,t_0+\epsilon)$. It is not hard to show that the open set you want in the domain is $Y\times (t_0-\epsilon,t_0+\epsilon)x_0$.

Comment: Thank you, but here $Y$ and $\mathbb{R}x_0$ is the direct sum, not the direct product...

Answer (score 1):

Or just use sequences: if $z_n:=y_n+t_nx_0\to 0$ then $t_n\to 0$ (because $x_0\notin Y$ and $Y$ is closed.) Then, $\gamma(z_n)=t_n\to 0.$

Comment: Thank you. If $\{t_n\}$ is a convergent sequence, then $\{t_n\}$ has to converge to $0$, but what if $t_n$ is not convergent sequence?

Comment: Look carefully: $z_n$ is defined by $z_n=y_n+t_nx_0$ and we are assuming that $z_n\to 0$. This forces $t_n\to 0$ because if not then one has $0=\lim y_n+x_0t=y+x_0t$ and since $Y$ is closed $\lim y_n=y\in Y$ so then $x_0=-y/t$ which puts $x_0$ in $Y$ and that is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, but we don't know ${y_n}$ and ${t_n}$ are convergent sequences. We only know ${z_n}$ is convergent.

Comment: Since the projections are continuous, $\pi_1(z_n)=y_n\to 0$ and similarly for $\pi_2.$ or you can do it by hand: if $z_n\to 0$ but either $y_n$ or $t_n$ does not, then.....??

Comment: Why are projections continuous? That's my original question. :)

Comment: For $\pi_1$: if $V$ is open in $Y$, then $\pi_1^{-1}(V)=V\oplus \mathbb Rx_0$ which is open in $Y\oplus \mathbb Rx_0.$ You can avoid projection altogether if you do it by hand and that is the thrust of my answer.

Comment: Could you explain to me why $V \oplus \mathbb{R}x_0$ is open $Y \oplus \mathbb{R}x_0$?

Comment: it's just the definition of the topology on the direct sum, i.e. the disjoint union topology.

Comment: Thank you. It is possible to equip $Y \oplus \mathbb{R}$ with the disjoint topology and with that topology, the projection maps are continuous. However, since $X$ is a topological space, $Y \oplus \mathbb{R}$ has the inherited topology. This topology is the same as the disjoint topology? Otherwise, it is still hard to say projections are continuous.

Comment: Just use the definitions: If $U$ is open in $Y\oplus \mathbb Rx_0$ in the disjoint union topology, then  $U$ is open in $Y$ or $\mathbb Rx_0$. But the summands are subspaces of $X$ and so have the subspace topology. Then there is an open set $O$ in $X$ such that $U=O\cap Y$ or   $U=O\cap \mathbb Rx_0.$ So $U$ is open in the subspace topology on the direct sum. The other direction is similar.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to understand your argument but still have some difficulty. However, I found that there is the exact same problem and its solution in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis. It is Thm 5.19.

Comment: Of course there are different proofs. My proof is with sequences, which is what  we were discussing. Rudin's proof is, of course, slicker.

Comment: Can you introduce me to a good book which deals with disjoint union topology? I have James Munkres' topology, but that book doesn't seem to deal with it. Or any other webpage? Thank you.

Comment: I think Kelly's book covers it but [here](http://uregina.ca/~franklam/Math535/Math535_0907.pdf) is a link that gives the basic construction.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will read them carefully, and get back to here. By the way, are you a professor at some university and your specialty is topology?